# hpricot in netbeans

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans, controller, jruby, hpricot

I am trying to use hpricot in JRuby.
My problem is the following. If I have this code:

```
 #!ruby
 require 'hpricot'
 require 'open-uri'
 # load the RedHanded home page
 doc = Hpricot(open("http://redhanded.hobix.com/index.html"))
```

where do I put it?
Into my controller? Because its not accepting it there.
And if I'm supposed to put it in my model. How can I call it frm my view?

Thank you

it gives me this error when trying the wired.com website

> Errno::ENOENT in
>   ProductsController#create
>
> No such file or directory - File not
>   found - www.wired.com
>
> RAILS_ROOT: H:\Documents and
>   Settings/owner/My
>   Documents/NetBeansProjects/RailsApplication5

Comment: If you are talking about controllers, models and views, do I assume correctly that you are using JRuby on Rails and you'd like to use Hpricot with Rails?

Comment: okay, answer is coming soon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting Rails to understand and see Hpricot is not very hard to do.

1. Install Hpricot: `jruby -S gem install hpricot`.
2. In your Rails app, find the `config/environment.rb` file
3. Find the lines which start with `config.gem` in the file and add

   `config.gem "hpricot", :source => "http://code.whytheluckystiff.net"`
4. Now you'll be able to use Hpricot directly from a controller as in normal (J)Ruby code. I strongly advise not to put any kind of business logic into your views and only minimal conditionals for sanity and in order to keep things straight, readable and maintainable. Or if you follow the "skinny controllers, simple views, fat models" paradigm, you may be able to refactor the code and put the Hpricot calls directly into a method inside your model class that is accessible from the view.

Some code examples are below.

Example controller `RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/example_controller.rb`:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @doc = Hpricot(open("http://www.wired.com"))
    # here come some very serious calculations, queries etc.
  end
end
```

Example view `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/example/index.html.erb` using the controller:

```
<pre>
  <%= @doc ? @doc.to_s : "There is no content at the site" %>
  <!-- blablabla -->
</pre>
```

As I've mentioned, you might be able to push the `Hpricot(open(...))` call back to the model, but first give it a try like this. If it's working, refactor :)

Comment: it still gives me a "No such file or directory - File not found" error :S:S

Comment: Yeah, that hobix.com website link doesn't work, so try something more popular, like www.wired.com for the URL. Please, update your question with the full error message and stack trace, if possible.